# Convert Google script to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert the google script below to work with Excel. The script is perfectly working in google sheet until I decided to download a copy. Please help.

Thank you.

```
function copyTo(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var dupRow = "MedR";
  var copy = ss.getSheetByName(dupRow);
  copy.insertRowAfter(copy.getLastRow());
  copy.getRange(copy.getLastRow(),1,1,copy.getLastColumn()).copyTo(copy.getRange(copy.getLastRow(),1));
}
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sourceSheet = "Form"; 
  var destinationSheet = "MedR";

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var range = sheet.getRange("B4");
  var cell1 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange("F6");
  var cell2 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("F9");
  var cell3 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();  
  var range = sheet.getRange("I9");
  var cell4 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("E7");
  var cell5 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();  
  var range = sheet.getRange("I3");
  var cell6 = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();  


  targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);

 targetSheet.getRange("A2").setValue(cell1);
 targetSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(cell2); 
 targetSheet.getRange("C2").setValue(cell3); 
 targetSheet.getRange("D2").setValue(cell4); 
 targetSheet.getRange("E2").setValue(cell5); 
 targetSheet.getRange("F2").setValue(cell6); 

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
 sheet.getRange("B4").setValue("Search here");
 sheet.getRange("F9").setValue(0);

}
```

Comment: So, once you downloaded a copy, the script stopped working.  Are you sure the only thing you did was a download?  That seems like it shouldn't have broken the source.

Answer (score 0):

I just recorded the macro in Excel and polished the scripts. All good.